# Panel with a view that is filtered dynamically by taxonomy term

Tags: views, panels

I'm using D7 with the panels3 and views 3.

I've got a view of medical procedures which are categorized by medical specialty. I have doctors becoming members of the site and, using profile2, I'm having them choose a specialty from that some tax vocab. I have a view of these procedures and I want it to be filtered by the specialty(ies) that the logged in user has in their profile. i.e. I want only doctors who selected the 'surgeon' specialty to see procedures also tagged with the 'surgeon' term.

I've got a view content pane set up and I have a page created with page manager which holds this in a panel but I just can't figure out how to configure Contexts to get the filtering to work.

In the view's configurations under pane settings -> argument input I have selected "From Context". As the Contextual Filters I have chosen: Has taxonomy term ID.

Please help!!

:)

Answer (score 0):

To allow panels to provide the context, Under the pane settings, set the 'Required context' to 'Term ID' and besure that the 'Context is optional' setting is unchecked.